# disallow to call run() in a groovy script

Tags: groovy, scripting, infinite-loop, dsl

I am using a GroovyShell to run Groovy scripts in a JVM. The GroovyShell is using several AST customizers and some predefined methods defining a DSL. But I found by hasard that it was possible to write "run()" in any groovy script, making it to run in an infinite loop.

Does anyone know how to disallow calling "run()" in a script that is already running ?

I tried to override the script's invokeMethod and set a flag to disable the run method when the script is running... but whatever I do, I can still call this run() method in the script, it seems without going trough the script's invokeMethod.

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to every script you execute:

```
this.metaClass.run { null }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sure it will work... however I don't want to modify the script (and this line is a Closure, not allowed by my DSL). I would like to disallow to use run(), above, and define some kind of mutex, disabling the possibility to run a script from itself when it is running, but still allow to run it from a compiled java program.

Comment: Your requirement is a little strange to me. You want to allow the run method only if it is called by code which is not the script itself? I can think of a couple of ways to doing that, but it really depends on how you're implementing the DSL and it can't be in a truly general way (meaning you want a hack). Do you use GroovyShell? How?

Comment: I use a GroovyShell in a Java service to parse and run scripts, that have been written following my DSL's rules. So, these scripting files are not compiled and are run by the service, this is not strange at all I think. I have to limit the code possibilities in these files to the very few keywords of the DSL, and its syntax (run is not desired). The groovyshell parses one of theses files to obtain a groovy.lang.Script object, then a predefined Binding is set to the script, and script.run() is called (from the service).

Comment: But a script can run itself by calling this run method directly, even if it is already running... resulting in an infinite loop

Comment: "I have to limit the code possibilities in these files to the very few keywords of the DSL" - I think this means you need to parse the text and convert it to code yourself, otherwise, using GroovyShell allows people to pretty much use any Java/Groovy methods, including `System.exit()` and similar, making `run()` the least of your problems.

Comment: Not really, System can be disabled (I do it) by using a SecureASTCustomizer, and by defining some whitelists to allow method call from a tiny subset of object types. My only question is about this run() function that seems to be always mandatory.

Comment: Looks like you're doing it right :) Can't you blacklist `java.lang.Runnable` or something like that?

Comment: First of all, Thanks for your help :). No this kind of AST transformations won't work against this run method, unfortunately, because it is attached to the script object itself, and run() must exist. Indeed, to run the script, the programm must call myscript.run(), and this same method is accessible inside the script this way : this.run() or simply run(). The best things I found out are : log a warning when "run" is called (thanks to overriding the script's invokeMethod), or use a parser of my own before GroovyShell's, to detect the use of run and throw an exception. This is tinkered, dirty :/